# Notation clarification from the Wikipedia entry for the Law of Total Expectation

Tags: probability

In the "Proof in the finite and countable cases" section of the Wikipedia article for the law of total expectation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) it is written that:

> Let the random variables $X$ and $Y$, defined on the same probability space, assume a finite or countably infinite set of finite values. Assume that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is defined, i.e. $min(\mathbb{E}[X_{+}], \mathbb{E}[X_{-}]) < \infty$....

I'm  not sure what $X_{+}$ or $X_{-}$ mean in this context. Is this the set of events that, through the random variable mapping, map to a real number $r$ with $r \geq 0$ for the positive sign and $r < 0$ for the negative sign, or some other meaning? Any insights appreciated.

Comment: $X_{+}=\max \{X,0\}$ and $X_{-}=-\min \{X,0\}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok thanks (if you post this as an answer I will accept it).